# Standard term for "dense" subset of a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let us temporarily say that a subset $A$ of (the set of vertices of) an undirected graph $G$ is **dense** when each vertex of $G$ is adjacent to an element of $A$.  In other words, the (distance-$1$, open) neighborhood of $A$ is all of $G$.

> **Question 0:** I suppose there is a more standard term for this than "dense", which I just made up.  What is it?

Now let us consider the following invariant $\psi(G)$ of an undirected graph $G$: it is the largest number $n$ of pairwise disjoint dense subsets of $G$ (where "dense" is defined as above).  I.e., it is the largest $n$ such that we can find $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ pairwise disjoint subsets of $G$ such that every vertex of $G$ is a adjacent to an element of each one of the $A_i$.  (We agree that $\psi(G)=0$ if no dense subset exists, i.e., whenever some vertex is isolated.)

Evidently, $\psi(G)$ is at most the minimal degree $\delta(G)$ of $G$.

> **Question 1:** Does $\psi(G)$ have a standard name and/or notation?  If so, what is it?
>
> **Question 2:** Is there some literature pertaining to this quantity?

**Motivation:** Consider the information theory protocol where Alice is given a vertex $x$ of $G$ and must choose a neighbor $x'$ of $x$ which she will communicate to her accomplice Bob (Bob is not given the value of $x$); Alice is trying to communicate some information to Bob: the obvious protocol (namely, Bob receives the information $i$ where $x'\in A_i$) will allow Alice to pass $\log n$ bits of information to Bob where $n = \psi(G)$.  See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316797/is-there-a-theory-behind-these-puzzles-communicating-by-modifying-data) for a motivation of the motivation.

**Edit:** As [Michal Adamaszek](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/537646/michal-adamaszek) answers in the comments, the answer to question 0 is "total dominating" (in contrast, a "dominating" set $A$ is one such that every vertex of $G$ is at distance $\leq 1$ to a vertex in $A$).  Now knowing this, Google returns a concept closely related to my $\psi(G)$, namely the [**domatic number**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domatic_number) of a graph, which is the maximum number of pairwise disjoint dominating sets.  It therefore seems logical to call my $\psi(G)$ the "total domatic number", and some authors seem to have done so.

Comment: What you call dense is called a "total dominating set in a graph".

Comment: Why say "distance-1 open" ( just wondering about use of term open here) ?

Comment: @coffeemath I'm not too familiar with graph-theoretic terminology (which is rather at odd with terminology of other domains I'm more accustomed to), but I understand that the "closed" neighborhood of a vertex includes said vertex whereas the "open" nhbd does not.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thank you. This answers my question 0 and allows me to google answers very close to my questions 1 and 2: the term "domatic number" seems very close to my $\psi(G)$.